# NextJS dynamic route not working with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I've build a NextJS blog and want to write backend with NodeJS/Express for that blog to run in my local and then my own server.

And I wanted to use MongoDB/Mongoose to fetch blog posts data in my local.

I've created [slug].js file to show single blog post in my /posts/ directory.

In my index.js pages, I could achieve fetching all the posts data from my local and show all the blog titles without an error. So getStaticProps function working correctly with my mongoose.

But the problem is when i click the single post link in index page, i can't go to single blog post.When i click the link, nothing happens.

Also if i make a get request to single post page from postman application. No response is coming.

Instead of using my own database, i put some data top of the [slug].js page and i could use that data as a db succesfully.

Also if i copy the getStaticProps or getStaticPaths function from [slug].js file to another file to test. I can still receive the data from db.

Only in [slug].js file and only when i use my local db; single post page does not working.

Here is my [slug].js file:

```
import PostModel from "../../backend/models/PostModel";

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  // Return a list of possible value for slug
  const allPostData2 = await PostModel.find();
  const paths = allPostData2.map((post) => {
    return { params: { slug: post.slug } };
  });
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  // Fetch necessary data for the blog post using params.slug
  const slug = context.params.slug;
  const myPost2 = await PostModel.find({ slug: slug });
  return {
    props: {
      post: myPost2,
    },
  };
}

export default function PostPage({ post }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{myPost.title}</div>
      <div>This is a single post page</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors when running `next build` locally?

Comment: @juliomalves Yes, I've tried `npm run build` command and got this error: ```warn  - Restarted collecting page data for /posts/[slug] because it took more than 60 seconds


> Build error occurred
Error: Collecting page data for /posts/[slug] is still timing out after 2 attempts. See more info here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/page-data-collection-timeout ```

Comment: Is the `PostModel.find` call inside `getStaticPaths` returning the expected result? Could you show the `models/PostModel` code?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the application tries to run Mongoose queries before it finishes connecting to the database. I ran into a nearly identical problem with index.js and [slug].js pages not responding, and awaiting the Mongoose connection to finish before running the Mongoose queries fixed it for me. Here's an example based off the connection I used.

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";

// Use the global mongoose connection if it exists
const cached = global.mongoose || {
  conn: null,
  promise: null
};

// Connect Mongoose to a database
async function mongooseConnect() {
  if (!cached.promise) {
    cached.promise = mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://username:password@host/database");
    cached.conn = await cached.promise;
  }

  return cached.conn;
}
```

Then just import and await the `mongooseConnect()` function before running Mongoose queries.

```js
import PostModel from "../../backend/models/PostModel";
import { mongooseConnect } from "../../path/to/lib/file.js"; // IMPORTANT!

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  await mongooseConnect(); // IMPORTANT!
  // Return a list of possible value for slug
  const allPostData2 = await PostModel.find();
  const paths = allPostData2.map((post) => {
    return { params: { slug: post.slug } };
  });
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  await mongooseConnect(); // IMPORTANT!
  // Fetch necessary data for the blog post using params.slug
  const slug = context.params.slug;
  const myPost2 = await PostModel.find({ slug: slug });
  return {
    props: {
      post: myPost2,
    },
  };
}
```

If the pages still aren't responsive, you can try passing `{ bufferCommands: false }` as a connection option parameter and see if it helps. For more information, see the official [Mongoose connections documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html).